# Exemples de phrases avec « (se) coltiner »

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

Je vous saurais gré de bien vouloir me donner quelques exemples de phrases avec l'expression *(se) coltiner*. Pas dans le sens de « se faire infliger quelque chose de pénible » (la vaisselle, la belle-mère etc.) mais dans le sens littéral de porter avec peine. Je me demande aussi si ce verbe est courant, s'il est connu par le commun des mortels en francophonie et si la forme pronominale est davantage usitée que la forme simple.

Answer (score 5):

Le verbe *coltiner* dans le sens de porter une lourde charge n'est plus très courant.  Les réalités qu'il décrivait ont disparu du monde moderne de même que les portefaix, les faquins et les forts des halles.

On voit sur l'image suivante un coltineur (http://www.crcb.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Course-des-coltineurs-Le-Petit-Journal-25-03-1893.jpg). Porte-t-il le coltin qui lui protège le cou et les épaules ?  C'est peut-être Jean Lebas, vainqueur du pari des coltineurs en 1893, qui a transporté une charge de 100 kg de Paris à Corbeil (32km) en 14 heures.

Quant au chapeau à larges bords appelé lui aussi *coltin* dont les forts des halles se couvraient le chef (http://www.paris-a-nu.fr/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Carte-postale-ancienne-1003-PARIS-Les-Forts-des-Halles1.jpg), on n'en voit plus guère.

C'est *se coltiner* qui subsiste et avant tout au sens figuré.  *Se coltiner la vaisselle*, ce n'est pas la porter mais la faire, *se coltiner les enfants*, c'est s'en occuper.  Le sens de porter une charge existe toujours et je pense qu'il est largement compris comme dans *se coltiner un frigo lors d'un déménagement*.

Comment: +1 et merci pour le rapport avec le *coltin* que je ne connaissais pas. Après, pour l'usage courant (de la forme non pronominale) c'est peut-être une question d'époque, si Audiard la met dans la bouche d'un chauffeur de taxi dans *Les tontons flingueurs* ("j'ai coltiné les bagages à la troisième baraque.") ce doit être qu'elle est usuelle à cette époque (début des années 60) ou, à minima, comprise par tout le monde et représentative d'un certain milieu.

Comment: @aCOSwt  Ta remarque est juste.  Sur "coltiner" et "se coltiner", j'hésite en fait.  Je ne sais pas si je dirais "on a coltiné le frigo jusqu'au troisième étage" (dans un déménagement) ou bien "on s'est coltiné le frigo jusqu'au troisième étage".  Les deux peut-être avec nuance de travail pénible pour le deuxième.

Comment: Je dirais que cela dépend... si des potes sont venus te donner un coup de main. :-) Pour une raison que j'ignore, le **on se / on s'est** est récurrent en situation de compagnie. *On se mange un truc / On se fait une toîle / On se boit un coup...*). Donc il n'y aura pas photo : Impersonnel+pronominal pour le frigo si tu n'es pas tout seul.

Answer (score 2):

Ce verbe est courant mais pas dans le sens où vous l'entendez, seulement dans son emploi pronominal populaire et familier, c'est à dire le sens « B » du TLFi ;

> [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coltiner) B. En constr. pronom., arg. et pop. Se coltiner qqc. Porter quelque chose de lourd.
>
> - Le facteur il avait sa claque... Il se coltinait trois fois par semaine des sacs entiers de manuscrits... (CÉLINE, Mort à crédit, 1936, p. 589).
>
> Au fig. Faire un travail fatigant, pénible ou inintéressant.
>
> - Je me suis coltiné toute la correspondance (DUB. 1967).

*quelques exemples de l'autre emploi*

> A. Emploi trans. Porter une charge sur l'épaule en s'aidant du coltin. Coltiner du charbon de terre (Lar. 19e).
>   P. ext., fam. Porter quelque chose de lourd, généralement sur l'épaule.

- (TLFi) Quand il apportait un paquet, même lourd et encombrant, il le coltinait tout seul.  (G. DUHAMEL, Chronique des Pasquier, La Passion de Joseph Pasquier, 1945, p. 72)
- (TLFi)  Même pour les postillons qui coltinaient les bagages, le pourboire était sévèrement interdit.  (P. ROUSSEAU, Hist. des transports, 1961, p. 61)
- Les orateurs pénétrèrent dans le moulin à papier tout retentissant du grondement des meules et avisèrent un premier ouvrier qui coltinait des bûches vers une cuve fumante.
  (*Revue des deux mondes - Page 23
  https://books.google.fr › books*)
- ... de nouveaux riches qu'ils sont ont oublié l'aïeul qui courait pieds nus sur la grève, en quête d'une aubaine hasardeuse ou coltinait les lourds ballots de marchandises exotiques. Ils sont de vieux riches maintenant, honorés, cultivés et bien …
  (*Revue des cours et conférences - Volume 23 - Page 432
  https://books.google.fr › books*)
- A quinze ans, il coltinait un échafaudage de ces panières girondines qui sentent l'estuaille et le potager. A seize ans, il criait les journaux sur l'Intendance. A vingt, frais débarqué à Paris, il entrait comme cycliste dans un grand quotidien.
  (*Les enfants du siècle - Page 29
  https://books.google.fr › books*)
- Debout à quatre heures le matin, il se précipitait au port, attendait les barques de pêche ou les maraîchers, coltinait ses sacs de provisions, mettait son déjeuner en train, puis, maître Jacques du cinéma, troquait son tablier contre le veston du …
  (*Les Oeuvres libres - Page 327
  https://books.google.fr › books*)

Answer (score 2):

Pour répondre à la deuxième partie de la question, la forme pronominale est largement usitée et unanimement comprise, alors que la forme simple est inusitée et inconnue de la majorité des locuteurs (au moins en France métropolitaine).